# when holding down two keys at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
                YUlt = YUlt - (PDiff + 10);
                Draw.AddEllipse(XUlt, YUlt, 20, 20, Colour); 
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                YUlt = YUlt + (PDiff + 10);
                Draw.AddEllipse(XUlt, YUlt, 20, 20, Colour); 
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
                XUlt = XUlt - (PDiff + 10);
                Draw.AddEllipse(XUlt, YUlt, 20, 20, Colour);
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                XUlt = XUlt + (PDiff + 10);
                Draw.AddEllipse(XUlt, YUlt, 20, 20, Colour);
                break;

        }
```

Ok so I'm trying to make a winform app where you draw circles with the keyboard. This program uses the GDIDrawer interface created by NAIT, but isn't important to know for this question so don't worry about Draw.AddEllipse.

The above switch case works perfectly fine to draw red dots, but the way the following if statement is supposed to function is that when the user holds down the F1 key and presses an arrow key, the dot that will be drawn will have a white border around it.

```
        if (Keys.F1 && (Keys.Down || Keys.Up || Keys.Left || Keys.Right))
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Up:
                    YUlt = YUlt - (PDiff + 10);
                    Draw.AddEllipse(XUlt, YUlt, 20, 20, Colour, 2, Color.White);
                    break;
                case Keys.Down:
                    YUlt = YUlt + (PDiff + 10);
                    Draw.AddEllipse(XUlt, YUlt, 20, 20, Colour, 2, Color.White);
                    break;
                case Keys.Left:
                    XUlt = XUlt - (PDiff + 10);
                    Draw.AddEllipse(XUlt, YUlt, 20, 20, Colour, 2, Color.White);
                    break;
                case Keys.Right:
                    XUlt = XUlt + (PDiff + 10);
                    Draw.AddEllipse(XUlt, YUlt, 20, 20, Colour, 2, Color.White);
                    break;

            }
        }
```

All I need to know is how to make it that the user can hold down the F1 key to give the dots borders when they press the arrow keys, but the program still draw dots regardless if F1 is pressed

Comment: wait. ... you want to draw dots when i press f1 and draw dots when i press arrows ? and also draw dots if f1 is not pressed ? why even use f1 whats the point of f1 ? i dont get it

Comment: The program draws dots regardless if F1 is pressed, it's just that if you hold down F1, a border will be around the dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add form field:

```
bool F1Pressed;
```

Subscribe to `KeyUp` event handler:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
        F1Pressed = false;
}
```

Your `KeyDown` method should look like this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.F1:
            F1Pressed = true;
            break;
        case Keys.Left:
            if (F1Pressed)
            {
                // draw dot with border
            }
            else
            {
                // draw dot without border
            }
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            if (F1Pressed)
            // and so on
    }
}
```